# In Notepad++, how do you replace all instances of a given character after the Xth instance PER LINE?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV I'm trying to format, but the input data has lots of commas to begin with.  It would be much easier if I could simply replace all commas on a given line (AFTER the 4th) with a semicolon.

Is there anyway to do this using a simple find/replace regex, or is programming required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (since Notepad++'s regexes don't support variable-length lookbehind assertions) to tackle this is probably to do it in three steps:

First, change the first four commas into something unique: Search for

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),
```

and replace with `\1#COMMA#\2#COMMA#\3#COMMA#\4#COMMA#`.

Then, replace all commas with semicolons.

Lastly, replace all `#COMMA#`s with commas.

This assumes that all lines with commas do have at least four of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with a regex in find/replace.
Try the following in Notepad++:

```
Find what:    ([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),
Replace with: \1,\2,\3,\4;
```

Don't forget to check the Regular Expression radio button.